# Page with changing backgrounds when you scroll down... how does it work?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I already googled this for a while, but simply can't find the answer. So, my question is: how do sites like this

http://tasag.de/

work? There are several background images that are shown behind the content box when you scroll down. When you scroll up and down you see that they occupy the whole screen, but sometimes you can see two of them, one at the upper an one at the lower part of the screen, at the same time. How does this work? I simply can't figure it out.

Thanks a lot

Comment: use `background:fixed` and `background:scroll` for this kind of effect

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the css of one of those backgrounds you find the key declaration:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

This means the background doesn't move, even when the user scrolls, allowing you can have different scrolling divs and the background will always look fixed

Here I prepared a sketchy fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3UpUb/

```
.container2 p{
    background-image: url(http://tasag.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/img-3-blur.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: auto;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: I think they also want to know how to trigger it when you get to it.

Comment: There's no triggering at all. If you use background: fixed, you can have that effect using css alone

Comment: then someone can use `window.scroll` for that @BeatAlex

Comment: I know that, I'm just saying this for the sake of OP :)

Comment: @Pixelpusher I added a fiddle to my answer to explain what I mean

Comment: @Jonas, Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I wanted to know...!

Comment: I always wanted to know too, but was too lazy to actually look it up ^^ anyway, could you mark my answer as accepted so I get my points? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Parallax scrolling and put the `speed` to `0`. Then the image stays fixed but will change when you scroll to next background image.

I used this [Parallax plugin](https://github.com/richardshepherd/Parallax-Scrolling).